# Generate mesh from depth information and RGB images

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, vtk, lidar

I would like to reconstruct a 3D object given a number of images and their associated (pixel-wise) depth information. Something along the lines of what [NeRFs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.08934) do. I found this python package ([vtk](https://kitware.github.io/)) but I'm not sure whether it is able to do what I want. What is a good package to build a mesh from RGB-images and depth information?

Example mesh:

[image: example_result]

Comment: [help/on-topic]: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are **off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: StackOverflow is a site to get help with specific code, not to find code for something you don't even know how you'd design, let alone implement. There are possibly other StackExchange sites on which you could ask this question in this way, but StackOverflow has pretty specific guidelines and I just don't see how this fits at all. The [tour] and the [ask] page go into more detail.

Comment: [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "but if your question generally covers software tools commonly used by programmers then you’re in the right place to ask your question!".

Comment: "Software commonly used by programmers" is things like IDEs and al that. You're asking for a specific niche thing, not something commonly used by programmers in general. Hence why I think you probably won't get much help from this site. I'm not telling you that you're wrong or bad for posting this, but I'm explaining why you might not get much help on StackOverflow.

Comment: [Computer vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision) questions are commonly asked within Stackoverflow and more so then in other [associated communities](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2794/stack-exchange-site-to-ask-questions-about-computer-vision), but sure photogrammetry and associated reconstructions are nevertheless quite niche.

Comment: Gotcha. https://ai.stackexchange.com/ might be more help, or something from this list of more ML-focused sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254090/858527